# Generate reports of similar web forms results

Tags: 7, views, webforms, log-messages

In Drupal 7, I want to generate a report of similar webforms (same fields but created 2 webforms to handle multilingual translations) results. All the fields in my both webforms are same. I tried to use Views to fetch the results of both webforms, which is not working.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

I did this to get the filename of teh fid saved in webform_submitted_data table.

Added SQL:

```
SELECT wsd.nid, wsd.sid, fm.filename, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN wsd.cid = 2 THEN wsd.data END) fn,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wsd.cid = 3 THEN wsd.data END) ln,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wsd.cid = 4 THEN wsd.data END) email,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wsd.cid = 5 THEN wsd.data END) ph,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wsd.cid = 6 THEN wsd.data END) tr,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wsd.cid = 7 THEN wsd.data END) upr,
       MAX(CASE WHEN wsd.cid = 9 THEN wsd.data END) coc
  FROM webform_submitted_data wsd LEFT JOIN file_managed fm ON wsd.data = fm.fid WHERE nid IN(66,67) GROUP BY wsd.sid;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) can't do what you're trying to do, you might want to consider the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module (disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer) as a possible alternative.

As an example, create a custom "data block" (which is just an SQL statement) that fits your needs, to retrieve the webform data that you're interested in. Here is a (basic) example:

```
SELECT s.nid AS node, s.sid AS submission, d.cid AS component, d.data AS fieldvalue
FROM {webform_submissions} s JOIN {webform_submitted_data} d ON s.sid=d.sid 
WHERE d.cid=3 AND s.nid=5
ORDER BY s.sid ASC
```

Then create a Forena "report" that uses this data block (maybe you want to enable something like the "CSV" option, within "document types"). Here is the (basic) layout of such report to illustrate the idea:

```
<body>
<div id="webform_submissions_data_block" class="FrxTable" frx:block="drupal_cust/webform_submissions_data">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>node</th>
          <th>submission</th>
          <th>component</th>
          <th>fieldvalue</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr id="webform_submissions_data" frx:foreach="*">
          <td>{node}</td>
          <td>{submission}</td>
          <td>{component}</td>
          <td>{fieldvalue}</td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

After you saved the report specifications and then browse the generated report, you could have a "CSV"-hyperlink (upper right of the report). Just use that link and ... voilà, there is your CSV file (in this case with 4 columns, since that is what in my (basic) report I asked for).

If this makes sense, head of to the Community documentation of Forena to get you going (which includes pointers to video tutorials). Or use the documentation that comes with Forena.

Of course, building the appropriate SQL statement to perfectly fit your needs is going to be crucial. But apart from that, it's just basic usage of Forena.

**Update**

To "*create a temporary table*" (as in your comment below this answer, and also per your updated question), you may want to have a look at what's suggested (by David Metzler) in [this feature request](https://www.drupal.org/node/2192829). Though I personally have no experience with using Forena to create such temporary tables.

Reminder: Forena is to *query* data (as in your first version of your question), not to update, delete, etc such data.

Comment: Hi Pierre, Thanks for your input. I am trying to create temporary table and create as a data source. Is it possible to use multiple queries while creating data source. I gave the exact sql in database where I got results, but its not workin in Forena data source. Updated the query in my question itself. Please check

Comment: @Kiran check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks Pierre for your suggestion of using Forena reports. Finally, got yhe correct query to use as data source.

Comment: @Kiran merci for he accept (and +1). It's always nice when (new) users provide this kind of feedback about a module that not a lot of users seem to know about. How about you add your own answer also to include the SQL and FRX-file (= complete set of your report specs) you came up with, eg with something like "using the previous answer, I was able to solve my question like so and so"? If you do, +1 from me for sure (and possible extra comments to further refine your solution. OK?

Comment: How to use PHP variables in forena reports layout?